# In libgdx, how do I calculate the rotation needed to rotate a modelInstance based on two sets of coordinates?

Tags: 3d, rotation, libgdx, transform, angle

I am trying to test out ways to orient a capsule based on two sets of coordinates. I add the models to the `world` the same way it is done in the libgdx examples. They have no mass so no bodies are created, just `modelInstances`. `endPoints[2]` hold the `xyz` floats of the two coordinates to be used. The coordinates will be variable but for testing purposes I hard coded values. `dir1` is the `vector3` basically saying the model is pointing up. `dir2` is the `vector3` created from subtracting one coordinate from the other to get the vector direction. I've tried normalizing this vector but end up with even weirder results. `dist` is the length of the vector so I know the height of the capsule to be created. I'm sure I can scale it eventually, but this is for testing the rotation so I'm not worried about that yet.

`BaseEntityModeled` is similar to `BulletEntity` in the libgdx examples and `BaseEntityModeledConstructor` is similar to `BulletConstructor`. The latter puts the plans in storage to be used later while the former creates the actual object to be rendered.

```
endPoints[0].set(-2000, 2000, -5000);
endPoints[1].set(2000, 4000, 2000);

Vector3 dir1 = new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
Vector3 dir2 = endPoints[0].cpy().sub(endPoints[1]);

float dist = endPoints[0].dst(endPoints[1]);

Model capsule = modelBuilder.createCapsule(250f, dist, 8, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE), new BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
world.addConstructor("capsule", new BaseEntityModeledConstructor(capsule, 0, null));

Model sphere = modelBuilder.createSphere(1000f, 1000f, 1000f, 16, 16, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED), new BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
world.addConstructor("sphere", new BaseEntityModeledConstructor(sphere, 0, null));

BaseEntityModeled theCapsule = world.add("capsule", 0, 0, 0);

BaseEntityModeled sphere1 = world.add("sphere", endPoints[0]);
BaseEntityModeled sphere2 = world.add("sphere", endPoints[1]);

float k_cos_theta = dir1.cpy().dot(dir2.cpy());
float k = (float) Math.sqrt(dir1.cpy().len2() * dir2.cpy().len2());
Vector3 rotAxis = dir1.cpy().crs(dir2);

theCapsule.transform.setToRotation(rotAxis, k_cos_theta + k).trn(endPoints[0].cpy().add(endPoints[1]).scl(0.5f));
```

From what I've been able to understand, the formulas at the bottom should calculate the `Vector3` and the angle needed to rotate the object, but they're not coming out right. I am completely stuck.

The `spheres` are placed on the coordinates so I am able to verify whether or not the capsule is lined up correctly.

Comment: `transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Y, tmp.set(endPoints[0]).sub(endPoints[1]).nor());`

Comment: So the Vector3 itself represents the angle? Then at that point you're just spinning it around the Y-axis. In my head I felt the need to have an angle to represent that Vector change. Even started looking at Quaternions. Thanks.

Comment: No, that method calculates the cross and dot product for you.